# Forming queries with comparison query operators and ISODate from groovy to get data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Here is my sample JSON from eventSchedule collection in mongodb:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51cd841b8b757a8c4c3b0af9"),
  "type" : "evo",
  "eventInfo" : {
    "title" : "My title",
    "field1" : "MyField1",
    "schedule" : {
      "fromDate" : ISODate("2013-07-19T04:00:00Z"),
      "toDate" : ISODate("2013-07-25T20:00:00Z")
    }
  },
  "locationName" : "Loc1"
}
```

I want to query this collection and get all eventSchedules with schedule field "fromDate" after the present date.

In mongoVUE, following query works:

```
db.eventSchedule.find({ "eventInfo.schedule.fromDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2012-04-29T00:00:00Z") } }).limit(50);
```

I am trying to do it from one of my grails controller as:

```
    def curDate= new Date()
    def sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")
    def curFormattedDate= sdf.format(curDate)
    def queryVal=  "{\$gte : ISODate(\""+curFormattedDate+"T00:00:00.000Z\")}"
    query.put("eventInfo.schedule.fromDate:", queryVal.trim())
    DBObject a = db.eventSchedule.findOne(query)
    println a
```

Above code returns the value of a to be null. Pls note that if i remove the enclosing braces from `queryVal`, then also it does not work.So can anyone help me form the appropriate query in groovy?

Comment: You aren't using the [MongoDB GORM](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) plugin available for Grails?

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes! I am using 1.3.0 version of GMongo.

Comment: Doesn't just doing `db.eventSchedule.findOne( [ 'eventInfo.schedule.fromDate': [ '$gte': new Date() ] ] )` work?

Comment: @tim_yates no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few areas where you need to rectify creating the query:

1. `mm` in date format represents minutes and not Month. Use `MM` instead.
2. Don't you need to escape `"` for `$gte` if you really want to stick to the mongoVUE version?
   `def queryVal=  "{\"\$gte\" : ISODate(\""+curFormattedDate+"T00:00:00.000Z\")}"`

BTW, a groovier way to format date is

`def currentFormattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: The following DBCursor cursor = db.ewhet.find(['$gte':'ISODate(2013-07-14T08:44:17.761Z)']) is not working.What can be done?I even tried new Date(),'new Date()' instead of ISODate.Pls could u suggest some way out?

Comment: I tried using this query for date range db.myCollection.find(date : ['$gte':'ISODate(2013-07-14T08:44:17.761Z)']). it gives empty result. did it work for anyone with ISO date from groovy to mongodb?